# Active users mismatch between Googleplay console and Firebase console

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

There is a mismatch between Active users count in Google Play console and Firebase console.

We can see 10k active users (30 days average) on Google play console but only 3.1k active users on firebase console.

Really appreciate if someone explains what this difference meant.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: @Mr.Robot, This is the response I got from reddit.
`They measure different things.

Google Play measures users who have your app installed on at least one device that was active in the preceding 30 days. That means it's based on "installs".

Firebase measures the users by user engagement. That means it's based on "usage".

Hence, Firebase will always report lower numbers for active users. If you get the same number of users in Firebase as you do in Play, this means that 100% of users who installed, used the app for the time period you're looking for.`